# Change of variable formula in double integrals vs. coordinate system transformation

Tags: calculus

There is a similar question I found but not exactly what I need. Is the variable formula in double integral calculus that uses the Jacobian  matrix a type of coordinate system transformation?  As for example when you rotate axis or you translate an axis. Another example would be changing the basis so a new grid appears but is distorted relative to the original grid. Perhaps you see my confusion now.  Is the Jacobian a General case for changing the coordinate grid so that when you change variables with the change of variable formula in double integrals you are really transforming the x, y grid to some new location. As for example transforming to polar coordinates would be a special case or is coordinate grid transformation a different concept and not related to the Jacobian matrix.  Thank you.  This has been confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change of variables formula handles all coordinate changes. The ones you see with spherical, polar and cylindrical coordinates are just special cases.